# Excel Cell Reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a formula `=address(2, match(I5, 2:2))` that returns a string "`E2`". When I try to nest my formula with in a `=Hlookup ("A", address(2, match(I5, 2:2)):E1000,2,false)`, I get a `error message`.

I think I know why I'm getting an error message because i'm mixing up string and range reference here, but does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

I don't think that indirect is what I'm looking for here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Address which returns a string that then needs to use INDIRECT to parse, use INDEX and save a step as well as remove the volatile functions of ADDRESS and the needed INDIRECT:

```
=Hlookup ("A", Index(2:2,match(I5, 2:2)):E1000,2,false)
```

But if you want the slower method of ADDRESS, which I would not recommend, then:

```
=Hlookup ("A", INDIRECT(address(2, match(I5, 2:2))&":E1000"),2,false),
```

Comment: My apology. Vlookup function should be Hlookup. Perhaps I wasn't clear. E2 is the cell address that was returned as a string from my address formula, it's not the actually value in Cell(E2). Essentially I want to convert a string "E2" into a cell reference without referring to the actually value in Cell E2.

Comment: @user7433793 I edited it to be Hlookup.  The `Index(2:2,match(I5, 2:2)):E1000` will return the E2:E1000 reference to the formula.

Comment: @user7433793 still trying to get my head around what you are trying to do.  I do not think HLOOKUP or VLOOKUP is what you want.  If you edit your OP with data and expected outcome we may be able to suggest a better formula.

Comment: My hlook up range is dynamic, I do not know which column, but i know it's between row 2:1000. I use the address function to return the starting cell for my Hlookup, say in this case is E2, so I can construct my HLookup function. Hopefully that clears up some confusions.

Comment: Not really as the HLOOKUP will then expect "A" to be in E2 and it will return the value in E3. @user7433793 . If this is not what you want then as I asked supply some mock data and expected outcome.

Comment: Address(2,5) returns $E$5, HLOOKUP("A",ADDRESS(2,5):E10000,2,FALSE) won't work. If you know how to solve this issue will be great.

Comment: I showed you two ways to make this work, above.  @user7433793 ,  But I would use, `=INDEX(3:3,MATCH(I5,2:2,0))` instead.